# Android in-app downloader with progress bar?

Tags: android

I'm trying to download mod files for a game to a specific folder and I'm having some troubles. I have the download code made, but it crashes the app, and I wanted to make a progress bar go with the download, but not quite sure how to. Here's my code:

```
package com.dogger20011.mcpemodlocater;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class v090 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.v090);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DownloadFromUrl();
        }
    });
}

public void DownloadFromUrl() {
    try {

        URL url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/uc? 
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkRlpXelpheGtnZUE&export=download");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +      
"sdcard/Android/data/com.snowbound.pockettool.free/Patches/";
        Log.v("PortfolioManger", "PATH: " + Path);
        File file = new File(Path);
        file.mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("shader mod.mod");

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[702];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("PortfolioManger", "Error: " + e);
    }
    Log.v("PortfolioManger", "Check: ");
}

}
```

07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): Process: com.dogger20011.mcpemodlocater, PID: 1084
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.dogger20011.mcpemodlocater.v090.DownloadFromUrl(v090.java:43)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.dogger20011.mcpemodlocater.v090$1.onClick(v090.java:31)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-13 16:13:40.537: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Don't you need a progress bar somewhere? That's the first step you need to take. Why not think it through and give it a try at least.

Comment: What I want to know first is why its crashing, if you want I could post my logcat

Comment: Yes, please always provide a logcat when you've got errors.

Comment: I just added my logcat to the original post. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in your logcat -

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 07-13 16:13:40.537:

-you're running your network code on the main thread. The [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask) training guide explains that network operations should be performed on a separate thread.

> Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations on a separate thread from the UI.

You'll find information on the correct way to do it at the link as well.